# Velocity JS slide and scroll

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

So I have some text on a page that is hidden and when I click a button the text is revealed with a "transition.slideDownIn' and when a button is clicked the text is hidden again using a "transition.slideDownOut". The problem is that the reader is left further down the page and I want them to be brought pack up to the parent div of the text which is slid down/up, ideally animated simultaneously with the slideDownOut. I have tried several different things (queues, etc) but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Am I approaching to problem incorrectly or misusing the functions?

Below is my most recent attempt.

```
   $read_close.velocity('transition.slideDownOut', 1000, function() {
     $('#services').velocity("scroll", {duration:1000, easing: "spring"} );
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wish to accomplish is simply scroll back up after the transition then do something like:

```
$read_close.velocity(
    'transition.slideDownOut',
    {duration: 1000,
     complete: function () {
         $('#services').velocity('scroll', {duration:1000, easing: "spring"});
     }});
```

Assuming your `scroll` call is correct.

Comment: Thanks. this is what I was looking for. I was also having issues with CSS overflow on a parent container which was causing problems computing the height to scroll too.